# Загрузка файла, каждые 5 минут, по ftp на хостинг

Tags: хостинг

Кто подскажет: как загружать файлы каждые 5 минут по ftp на хостинг. Может есть программы, способы, благодарна за любую помощь.

Comment: Штатный планировщик и любой ftp-клиент командной строки.

Comment: @Akina, Если Вам не сложно то Вы не можете подсказать более подробно?

Comment: [rsync](https://ru.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsync) более подходит для этих целей

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Делаем файл с командами ftp, например с именем commands.ftp:

```
put file.txt
by
```

Под windows:

```
ftp -s:commands.ftp ftp://user:password@host
```

под Unix/Linux:

```
ftp ftp://user:password@host < command.ftp
```

Вставляем эти комманды в планировщик

Или на любом скриптовом языке пишем скрипт обмена по FTP и вставляем этот скрипт в планировщик

Comment: А вот интервал где тут можно установить ?

Comment: Интервал выставляете в планировщике. Под линуксом cron под windows "планировщик windows" в панели "администрирование"

Comment: А программ подобного рода не существует?

Comment: Не встречал. Во всех gui фтп клиентах тоже используется командная строка для таких целей